# How To Add paragraph alignment to a Pug template?

Tags: node.js, html, express, pug

I have this code currently, :

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title

        style.
            body {
                font-family: Verdana;
                font-size: 13px;
                background: #42f495
            }
    body
    h1 Welcome!
    h2 Please Wait

p= sq
```

I want to align paragraph to center but not getting how to do it using Pug.

Comment: I believe what you're wanting to do is add an attribute to your PUG markup. Here is the documentation: https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to indent all of the tags to be further in than the `body` tag to make this all work properly.

To assign a style to a paragraph do this:

```
p(style="text-align:center;")
```

Here are two different ways to assign a css class to a paragraph (they will produce the exact same results):

```
style.
  .cssClassExample { text-align:center; }

p.cssClassExample

p(class="cssClassExample")
```

If you want to assign a class based on a pug variable do this:

```
- var cssClassVariable = "myClass"

p(class= cssClassVariable)
```